# How to become aware when DatagramSocket is in a receive state

Tags: java, multithreading, udp

I am running a UDP Java implementation using DatagramSocket where the receive is running on one thread and the sending operations are run on a separate thread.  When my program starts up, I need to make a call out to a server and receive information back.  The problem is, due to the threading, even though I start my receiving thread first, sometimes the send will go out first and when the server replies, the socket has not called receive() yet in the other thread.  Since this thread blocks on the receive() line, I can't use a flag to verify that receive() has been called. Is there any way to check if the socket is currently blocking on receive() so that I can wait to send until I verify that condition?

Comment: Uh, brain is logging out, but would this be a case for a `CountDownLatch`? Feel free to put it in an answer, got to sleep.

Comment: @owlstead: perhaps the sending thread in the question should `thread.sleep` as well :)

Comment: The problem is because receive() blocks and waits, I can't decrement the countdown latch since it doesn't progress past that point.

Comment: Ok, send a datagram to youself until it is received, then send it to the other party (woken up again).

Comment: @Patrick possibly combined with the test I wrote above, yes, but waiting a second should do the job nicely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start the tx thread from the rx thread just before the recvfrom() loop and put a sleep(2000) at the start of the tx thread before it too starts loping around its input queue, or whatever it does normally to get stuff to send.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need two sockets.

1. Create a single `DatagramSocket.` It is in a 'receive state' immediately.
2. Start a receiving thread that receives over the `DatagramSocket.`
3. Start a sending thread that sends over the `DatagramSocket.`

The order of (2) and (3) doesn't really matter any more.